# Android PhoneGap PHP Code

Tags: java, php, android, cordova

I am currently creating an app with the phonegap framework for android. Is it possible for the app to run PHP code without the need of an external server? Such as a local AJAX PHP app?
Thanks

Comment: Phonegap is for running HTML code (cross-platform). Not PHP. You can have PHP as back-end, though, and there should't be any problem getting the app to work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849674/can-i-use-php-with-phonegap

Comment: php is server side scripts not client side. you can load php driven pages from your web server. You need  a php enabled web server.

Answer (score 2):

Phonegap is html5 library which is client side, PHP is server side scripting language it needs an interpreter to run which in most cases apache server so no you can't in short

> What is PHP?
>
> PHP is a widely-used general-purpose scripting language that is especially suited for Web development and can be embedded into HTML. If you are new to PHP and want to get some idea of how it works, try the introductory tutorial. After that, check out the online manual, and the example archive sites and some of the other resources available in the links section.

check the php website [here](http://www.php.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, because PHP is a server side scripting language